# ValueError exception not beign handled with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, exception, valueerror

My issue is `ValueError` which is rising, because of bad formatting of my datetime string.

```py
# month is given. Sometimes with seconds as '.Z' (int) and sometimes as '.0000Z' (float)
try:
    next_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(month, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
except ValueError:
    print('asd')
    next_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(month, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

next_month += relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
```

Django error trace stack is hard to copy, but here is the `raise`:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %(data_string, format))
```

With this, I'm pretty sure, it's about `datetime`. (about datetime, hehe)

Found some questions on this topic, but none of proposed solutions worked. Most of them where about not placing the exact piece of code that generates this error in `try-except`.

> The question is: why does `ValueError` is not being handled ?

> EDIT: reporoduction snippet:

Below code run in PyCharm (python3.7, same as in above use), does not reproduce this error.

```py
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d1 = '2021-03-24T11:20:33Z'
    d2 = "2021-03-10T20:45:01.036000Z"
    d = d2 # for quick change

    try:
        next_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        print('try: ', next_month)
    except ValueError:
        next_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        print('except: ', next_month)
```

> EDIT2:

In django error page: `ValueError at /api/sessions_stats_csv/`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
django_server_dev |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_server_dev |     response = get_response(request)
django_server_dev |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
django_server_dev |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_server_dev |   File "/app/label_it/rest_api/statistics_view.py", line 334, in AllSessionsDetailsCSV
django_server_dev |     rows = ExtractSessionsForUser(item, params['for_month'])
django_server_dev |   File "/app/label_it/rest_api/statistics_view.py", line 485, in ExtractSessionsForUser
django_server_dev |     format_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
django_server_dev |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
django_server_dev |     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
django_server_dev |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
django_server_dev |     raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
django_server_dev | ValueError: time data '2021-03-24T11:20:33Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Comment: could you clarify: how *exactly* does the timestamp string look like? "*Sometimes with seconds as '.Z' (int) and sometimes as '.0000Z' (float)*" isn't clear to me

Comment: `"2021-03-11T07:55:43.906000Z" `as float;
`"2021-04-14T11:20:15Z"` as int.
`'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' ` and `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` are able to handle those. I've checked.

Comment: ok thanks. my next question is what you're actually trying to achieve. with the upper code sample, you're trying to *catch* the error that is risen? looking at the code, I notice that you try one format, if that doesn't work (exception triggered), you try the next - but if that *also* doesn't work, you'll get into trouble.

Comment: `month` is filled with request param. This piece of code is in django rest view, which I call from my front-end. I could make sure, that only `float` like date formats are coming in, but hey- this is why we have exceptions. Answering, there is no other format coming in

Comment: so how does `raise ValueError...` actually print? copying a trace-back isn't that hard, selecting the relevant part is what matters ;-)

Comment: `ValueError at /api/sessions_stats_csv/

time data '2021-03-24T11:20:33Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'` is exactly what I get. Which (afaik) is not handling exception

Comment: In `EDIT2` You will find that django itself points me to this url `/api/sessions_stats_csv/` . In my project it is mapped to only one function. Besides this `ValueError` appeared with me intentionally placing `shorter` datetime format.